# Permission denied (publickey), but no solution worked

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

It's one of these issues that get asked and answered so many times here and elsewhere, you can't believe you have to ask it again.
I'll let my configuration speaks for me:

On remote:

```
# getenforce
permissive

# echo ~git
/var/lib/git

# ls -la ~git
drwxr-x---. 1 git  git  136 Jun 25 01:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 406 Jun 25 00:38 ..
drwx------. 1 git  git   30 Jun 27 16:03 .ssh

# ls -la ~git/.ssh
total 4
drwx------. 1 git git  30 Jun 27 16:03 .
drwxr-x---. 1 git git 136 Jun 25 01:39 ..
-rw-------. 1 git git 694 Jun 27 16:01 authorized_keys

# cat ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIId5JlesVpbIDm3bQoXDfrPkcCIoIwLdEp/Y0N0FDAHp Gentoo Laptop

# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
AllowUsers other_user git
```

On local:

```
# cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIId5JlesVpbIDm3bQoXDfrPkcCIoIwLdEp/Y0N0FDAHp Gentoo Laptop

# ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@[redacted]
git@[redacted]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Notes:

- I'm able to log in as other_user using the same key pair.
- I tried with `~git` moved to `/home/git/`
- sshd has been reloaded, several times.
- The machine was restarted (yeah, I'm THAT desperate!)

TLDR;

- .ssh's mode is 700,
- authorized_keys's mode is 600,
- user 'git' is allowed in sshd_config,
- pub key matches,
- the same key pair works with remote user 'other_user',
- and Selinux is permissive

Thank you for your consideration. Here's the verbose (-v) output:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/local_user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/local_user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for [redacted]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to [redacted] [redacted] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/local_user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/local_user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to [redacted]:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/local_user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Fnf3Oy6WVHq6XGivLolPglHXpq9JY277TNM6YdVJBQc
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/local_user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[redacted]' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/local_user/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/local_user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:EZKglMrsrAKRUkrGoRRkEMFxiNj0kWALw926e0YIu1o explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp3>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/local_user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:EZKglMrsrAKRUkrGoRRkEMFxiNj0kWALw926e0YIu1o explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@[redacted]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Hint: Use `namei -lx ~git` when confirming permissions on a path. It produces output similar to `ls -la`, but prints the expanded path as well as info on each element of the path in one call.

Comment: have you checked ```/etc/passwd``` if the shell for the user git is set to something like ```/bin/false``` or ```/sbin/nologin``` ?

Comment: @Martin User `git` is `git:!:19168::::::` in `/etc/shadow`.  No shell specified.

Comment: no, not the shadow file - you need the passwd file for that. you can query it with this command: ```getent passwd git```

Comment: My bad, I read your comment too hastily. `git`'s shell is `/usr/bin/git-shell`, no apparent problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the logging level of the *client* by adding more `-v` options, but in this case I guess the best explanation will be logged by the *server*.

Add a more verbose logging level (default: INFO) in your `sshd_config`:

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

Restart sshd and try connecting as that user again. Then read logs.

If the message supplied in the logs does appears to conflict with the sshd_config you reviewed, double-check whether you had skipped over includes (e.g. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*`).

Comment: First I got  `User git not allowed because account is locked`, so I gave `git` a password. Now I have `Failed publickey for git from [redacted] port 39334 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:5oz3VPSye0rM8a7Mgvb50wD5vIxOJu8kzSU5dJvC6nI`. This doesn't makes much more sense. Mind that I'm now using a different key from a different machine, hence why the hash doesn't appear in the first log dump.

Comment: @3Nd_R1m Try `grep "different machine" ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys | ssh-keygen -lf-` to generate the hash for the key you actually added, maybe you copied the wrong key or introduced some typo when appending the new key to your  `authorized_keys`  file?

Comment: The hash generated from `authorized_keys` and the one advertised by `ssh -v` match.